# What is the Difference Between Noun Number and Nominative Plural Case?

Tags: множественное-число

Noun number :

https://youtu.be/3qa8U-PmVU8

I used this video to help with my study but I couldn't seem to understand the difference and the usage. However, I saw some similarities with nominative plural case.

If you didn't want to watch the whole video, maybe this can give you an idea.

1st group :

1. Mas. nouns ending in a hard consonant.
2. Fem. nouns ending in -а.

{Forms (plural) : +ы }

Пример :

стол → столы

Улица →Улицы

**Question:** Are noun number and nominative plural case the same? If not, what are the differences?

Comment: It's the same thing множественное число существительных в именительном падеже.

Comment: please, tend to ask one question per post - not only having two questions violates the on-topic policy, it's completely unclear what are you asking in the first one - what do you mean by "what is the usage?" When to use plurals? I suggest you to get rid of one of the questions. 

Also, as a sidenote,  questions are supposed to be self-sufficient, so it's better always not to expect that someone will watch external video.

Comment: In Russian language nouns are (usually) declinable in both singular and plural. That means English plural, such as "tables", could correspond to one of six forms: столы, столов, столам, etc. But when people talk of "plural form" they usually mean Nominative plural (just like speaking of "singular" usually means Nominative singular). That's all.

Comment: It's the same. Singular is called "единственное число" in Russian (and "число" is "number"). Plural is called "множественное число". And "number" is also used in English as [grammatical category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number).

Answer (score 2):

You question does not make sense. In Russian we do have cases - generally speaking any noun can be declined by cases. Also in Russian we have plural, this is well, another grammatical category.

**A noun in the plural form also is declined by cases.**

That said, when somebody tell you that, for instance, `дом` in plural is `дома`, or plural for `девочка` is `девочки`, actually he / she means that it is the form of plural in nominative case. But actually you have also `домами`, `домах`, `девочками`, `девочках` etc.

**By default plurals are described in nominative declension**. 
So yes, it's still unclear what you are asking, but if I understand correctly your question the answer is yes, it's completely the same.

Answer (score 2):

I watched the video and found it a bit confusing even for a native speaker. She is trying to explain rules for forming plurals in the Nominative case.

Judging from the content of the video, what you are referring to as 'noun number' is simply singular and plural forms. Thus, for the purposes of this particular lesson noun number and nominative plural form are the same. However, you should not forget that Russian uses cases, therefore, plural forms change depending on a case. But, I suppose, it was going to be explained in further lessons.

I think these pages provide a better explanation of the rules:

- http://www.russianlessons.net/lessons/lesson11_main.php
- http://www.russianforeveryone.com/Rufe/Lessons/Course1/Grammar/GramUnit2/GramUnit2_1.htm